# How to skip row after headings laravel excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I just want to make the row of datas will rendered after headings

This's the result that i want
[this what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1j63.png)

But i only get this result
[this i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTdeS.png)

I already using startRow and set to 7, but nothing change
I have 6 row of heading, so how to render/display the data after headings, and i already return another collection with another model, but the result is same there's nothing change, the data keep displayed from first row

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

Importing Models...
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;

class TahapSeleksiExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithColumnWidths, WithStyles, WithEvents
{
    use RegistersEventListeners;

    protected $id;

    function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        $tahap = Tahap::where('id_tahap', $this->id)->first();
        if ($tahap->status == '0') {
            if ($tahap->tahap_ke == '1') {
                return Pelamar::select('pelamar.id_pelamar', 'alm.nama', 'jur.akronim', 'ang.angkatan', 'pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                    ->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)
                    ->join('alumni_mendaftar_pelamar as almPel', 'almPel.pelamar_id', '=','pelamar.id_pelamar')
                    ->join('alumni as alm', 'almPel.alumni_id', '=','alm.id_alumni')
                    ->join('jurusan as jur', 'alm.jurusan_id', '=','jur.id_jurusan')
                    ->join('angkatan as ang', 'alm.angkatan_id', '=','ang.id_angkatan')
                    ->orderBy('pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                    ->orderBy('jur.akronim')
                    ->orderBy('ang.angkatan', 'DESC')
                    ->get();
            }else{
                return SeleksiPelamar::select('pelamar.id_pelamar', 'alm.nama', 'jur.akronim', 'ang.angkatan', 'pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                    ->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)
                    ->join('pelamar', 'pelamar.id_pelamar', '=','seleksi_pelamar.pelamar_id')
                    ->join('alumni_mendaftar_pelamar as almPel', 'almPel.pelamar_id', '=','pelamar.id_pelamar')
                    ->join('alumni as alm', 'almPel.alumni_id', '=','alm.id_alumni')
                    ->join('jurusan as jur', 'alm.jurusan_id', '=','jur.id_jurusan')
                    ->join('angkatan as ang', 'alm.angkatan_id', '=','ang.id_angkatan')
                    ->orderBy('pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                    ->orderBy('jur.akronim')
                    ->orderBy('ang.angkatan', 'DESC')
                    ->where('keterangan', '1')->whereHas('tahap', function ($tahaps) use ($tahap) {
                            $tahaps->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)->where('tahap_ke', $tahap->tahap_ke - 1);
                    })->get();
            }
        }
    }

    public function columnWidths(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => 15,
            'B' => 40,
            'C' => 15,
            'D' => 15,
            'E' => 25,
            'F' => 12,
        ];
    }

    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        $sheet->getStyle(2)->getFont()->setBold(true);

        $sheet->mergeCells('A2:G2');
        $sheet->mergeCells('A3:G3');
        $sheet->mergeCells('A4:G4');
    }

    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();

        $sheet->getStyle(2)->getFont()->setSize(16);
        $sheet->getStyle(3)->getFont()->setSize(14);
        $sheet->getStyle(4)->getFont()->setSize(14);

        $sheet->getStyle('A6:G6')->getFont()
            ->setBold(true)
            ->getColor()->setRGB('ffffff');

        $sheet->getStyle('A6:G6')->getFill()
            ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()->setARGB('2041BB');
    }

    public function headings():array
    {
        $tahap = Tahap::where('id_tahap', $this->id)->first();

        return [ // PER ROW HEADINGNYA
            [], [$tahap->nama], ['Seleksi Alumni'], ['BKK SMKN 1 Kota Bekasi'],[],[
                'ID Pelamar',
                'Nama',
                'Jurusan',
                'Angkatan',
                'Tanggal Submit',
                'Nilai',
                'Lulus',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to add an empty array of data to the collection. The solution is not idle but I think it can works. Try this:

```
public function collection()
{
    $tahap = Tahap::where('id_tahap', $this->id)->first();

    $PelamarData = new Collection();

    if ($tahap->status == '0') {
        if ($tahap->tahap_ke == '1') {
            $PelamarData = Pelamar::select('pelamar.id_pelamar', 'alm.nama', 'jur.akronim', 'ang.angkatan', 'pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                ->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)
                ->join('alumni_mendaftar_pelamar as almPel', 'almPel.pelamar_id', '=','pelamar.id_pelamar')
                ->join('alumni as alm', 'almPel.alumni_id', '=','alm.id_alumni')
                ->join('jurusan as jur', 'alm.jurusan_id', '=','jur.id_jurusan')
                ->join('angkatan as ang', 'alm.angkatan_id', '=','ang.id_angkatan')
                ->orderBy('pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                ->orderBy('jur.akronim')
                ->orderBy('ang.angkatan', 'DESC')
                ->get();
        }else{
            $PelamarData = SeleksiPelamar::select('pelamar.id_pelamar', 'alm.nama', 'jur.akronim', 'ang.angkatan', 'pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                ->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)
                ->join('pelamar', 'pelamar.id_pelamar', '=','seleksi_pelamar.pelamar_id')
                ->join('alumni_mendaftar_pelamar as almPel', 'almPel.pelamar_id', '=','pelamar.id_pelamar')
                ->join('alumni as alm', 'almPel.alumni_id', '=','alm.id_alumni')
                ->join('jurusan as jur', 'alm.jurusan_id', '=','jur.id_jurusan')
                ->join('angkatan as ang', 'alm.angkatan_id', '=','ang.id_angkatan')
                ->orderBy('pelamar.tanggal_kirim')
                ->orderBy('jur.akronim')
                ->orderBy('ang.angkatan', 'DESC')
                ->where('keterangan', '1')->whereHas('tahap', function ($tahaps) use ($tahap) {
                    $tahaps->where('lowongankerja_id', $tahap->lowongankerja_id)->where('tahap_ke', $tahap->tahap_ke - 1);
                })->get();
        }


        //Add empty array data to skip the first 7 rows
        foreach (range(1, 7) as $item)
        {
            $PelamarData->prepend([]);
        }


        return $PelamarData;
    }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but nothing change 